# SQL loader, insert filename in import

Tags: sql-loader

I'm trying to import a data file that looks like
FileName: BND20160114.dat

The rows look something like this:

```
SPSTART;BN;20160114;083422;000026
SPINFO;15165446456;A1;20160114
SPINFO;54645465456;A1;20160114
SPSLUT;BN;20160114;083422;4
```

I've created a simple controlfile that imports the rows in a table.

```
load data characterset WE8MSWIN1252
APPEND INTO TABLE CSSE_IMP.STAGED_PERSON_LKD
fields terminated by ';' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    FILE_ROWNUM RECNUM,
    FILE_DATA POSITION(1:400),
)
```

My issue is that I'm am going to import more files that are similar to this file, and I need to know the origin of every file I import.
Either I import the filename for every row.
Or I get the the letters after the SPSTART; in the first row, and add that to every row.

I'm stuck. Could someone shed some light on this.

Thank!

Comment: Is the BND part of the filename significant?  otherwise it seems the rest of the filename is already there in the 3rd field of records where the first field = "SPSTART" or "SPSLUT".  Please add some more detail as else it just looks like you are trying to shove the whole row from the file into a column.Could the rows start with anything else besides what is shown?  On filename's data per data file?  Table layout?